# Cannot add a SQL Server project to a Visual Studio 2013 solution

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with SQL Server 2012.

When I try to add a SQL Server project (`*.sqlproj`) to my solution, I receive the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.12, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=etc...' or or one of its 
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

According to Microsoft, SQL Server Data Tools comes installed as part of the default installation with Visual Studio 2013.

Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Well, if anyone else has this problem then the Visual Studio 2013 repair fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

I've the same problem and found some decision possible it is suitable : http://sdksdotnetfunda.blogspot.com/2012/08/could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).